# ODBC Microsoft Access Driver Too few parameters

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm stuck with this problem for a while now, I'm trying to get data from a MS Access DB using python ODBC, but when I run the query I keep getting the error of the title.

My statement is like this:

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT Referencia, Cliente, Fornecedor, Evento, Custo, Início, Fim, Faturamento, Imposto, BU FROM qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT ", connA)
```

I've searched different questions regarding the same error but can't find a solution

the full error is:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Referencia, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Cliente, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Fornecedor, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Evento, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Custo, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Início, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Fim, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Faturamento, qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.Imposto , qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT.BU FROM qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT ': ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Edit: The connection works, I've tried a differente SQL that uses a simple table and it works

Comment: Could simplify that SQL - don't need to prefix each field name with table name, could even use wildcard. Are you sure connection is made? Do other queries work?

Comment: Also to simplify things, try using only plain old Ascii characters in the database, not special characters as in "Mês" and "Início".

Comment: @June7 I've simplified the SQL, sorry for that, and yes, I've tried another query that uses just simple tables instead of stored queries and it works fine

Comment: @Andre I'm not the owner of the db and can't edit it either, I agree with you, plain characters works better but it's out of my control

Comment: Does stored query have dynamic parameter? Try enclosing in brackets `[qryConsultasADMx_BI_Mês_VT]`. Do other table or field names use these accented characters?

Comment: I think it is bound to an Access Form in the where clause, it originally had this clause `WHERE  Year([referencia])=year([Formulários]![Extração de Dados]![txtRefIni])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run the query saved in MS Access with required parameters through Pyodbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922378/run-the-query-saved-in-ms-access-with-required-parameters-through-pyodbc)

Comment: I've tried this solution, no luck tough, maybe I will need to ask for access to the DB and rewrite those queries myself

Comment: Even coding in VBA, calling a query that has dynamic parameter referencing form control is an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442068/error-executing-a-saved-access-query-that-depends-on-parameter-values-from-a-for. I don't use dynamic parameter queries. I apply filter to form or report. But I don't use Python, only VBA. Exactly what does this stored query do besides apply filter? Could you pull from table and get filter criteria by user input some other way than form reference?

Comment: Wait, your query has parameters that refer to Form controls? That cannot work from outside Access.

Comment: @Andre Yes, so I will really need to rewrite the queries without the parameters right?

Comment: If the technique linked by June7 doesn't work, then yes.